# Problem with installing spartacussampledataaddon for use with Spartacus 3.0

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I've got a problem with setting my environment to work with Spartacus. I've started by following [documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2005/) and performed all operations step by step. Finally, I've obtained working local Commerce Cloud (2005.4) instance with `-spa` websites showing up in the Backoffice.

[Content of Backoffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDOv9.png)

Next, I've created fresh Spartacus 3.0 using [these docs](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/) and connected it to my Commerce. What I get is a storefront with non-working PDP, Search Result Page (B2B), etc. I'm getting `Translation key missing 'TabPanelContainer.tabs.TabPanelContainer' in the chunk 'product'` error all over the site.

[PDP error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lt0w.png)

I don't know what might be the source of the problem because I'm strictly following the official documentation. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addon "spartacussampledataaddon" was changed to "spartacussampledata" extension. Please download the "spartacussampledata", and try again. (https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2005/). Also please make sure the base-site configured in Spartacus is the "spa" site.